# How to get Cloudflare SSL to work with IIS website on Azure virtual machine

Tags: ssl, azure, virtual-machines, cloudflare

I have an Azure virtual machine running IIS.
The DNS goes through Cloudflare and I have turned SSL on there.
However, when I visit https://www.reainvite.com.au I get
"This site can’t be reachedwww.reainvite.com.au took too long to respond."

Below is a video covering all my setup

https://youtu.be/vi7ksa7Y8Qc

Can anyone let me know what to do?

Comment: You don't need the outbound NSG rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting **Full** End-to-End encryption for your Cloudflare setup.

This means Cloudflare is expecting to connect to an encrypted server, and proxy that connection to the end user. This means your back-end server, the IIS VM, needs a certificate installed, and needs to be bound to 443.

If you do not want to, or cannot, install the cert on your VM, you cannot use Full end-to-end encryption, and will need to select **Flexible** e2e.

This [Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024787372-End-to-end-HTTPS-with-Cloudflare-Part-1-conceptual-overview) help article provides an overview of how E2E encryption works, and what is required to get things working.

Comment: Thanks that has helped my understanding but not quite fixed it. See 1-minute video on the current states of system https://youtu.be/l9777nCIVUc

Comment: Are you able to browse the site over http if you connect to the VM's public IP?

Comment: You can see the site via IP here http://52.253.89.211/ But the https https://52.253.89.211/ still times out

Comment: That's ok, https to that address should fail. When I do a DNS lookup, your website is pointed to that IP address, not to Cloudflare. Do you have the Cloudflare proxy disabled, or set to DNS Only for the main address?

Comment: I have changed the CloudFlare setting to A records to Proxied:-

A
reainvite.com.au
52.253.89.211
Auto
Proxied

A
www
52.253.89.211
Auto
Proxied

Still no luck

Comment: Looks like you've figured it out between your last post and now. I'm able to connect to the site over https. Can you clarify what you had to do to get things working?

Comment: You are right, but I only found this out when I checked after reading your answer. It wasn't working when I performed the last action. Perhaps the DNS takes time to update. Anyway, steps were the Flexible option in CloudFlare SSL and proxied in DNS at CloudFlare. Thanks for your awesome help.

Comment: Happy to help! Thanks for clarifying what you had to do. You may want to look at restricting inbound http traffic to your VM, so that only Cloudflare can connect directly to your server. Cloudflare's IP addresses are listed here: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/